# using docker-compose , without creating new network i want to use static ip with existing ip series

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i just want to join my container into docker default network with static ip

,,,wait let me explain....

here i already used "network_mode : bridge" this line with **so many projects** 
so there ip series is 172.17.0.0 ( default docker series 172.17.0.X )

and this is from docker network ls

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                     DRIVER              SCOPE
dc8bd9c6cfc3        bridge                   bridge              local
```

this is already created network by docker with 172.17.0.0 series and the gatway is 172.17.0.1

so now the problem is i just want to give a static ip 172.17.0.50 into one mysql db container
i tired with

```
networks:
 default:
   external:
     name: bridge
```

, ignore the space and json format issues i just explaining...
this one return me

ERROR: for mysql  network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks

and tried this one

```
   networks:
     bridge:
       driver: bridge
        ipam:
          driver: default
             config:
            - subnet: 172.17.0.0/24
```

this one return me ip : 172.22.0.2 not 172.17.0.0 series

again tried with  this one

```
networks:
 bridge:
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
    driver: default
    config:
      - subnet: 172.17.0.0/24    
      - ipv4_address: 172.17.0.50
```

this one return me

ERROR: for mysql  user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets

simply say my problem is don't create "user defined networks" but need "static ip" with 172.17.0.x series

any solutions..??

Comment: You almost never need to specify a static IP address for a container, or really worry about the container-private IP addresses at all.  I'd highly recommend deleting your existing containers and recreating them on "user-defined" networks (or managing them with Compose); is there a specific reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: around 45 containers are working with 172.17.0.x series ip so right this moment i hope 
creating a user network is not a good , i know in the beginning i need to create one network , but it's too late so that's why i need this

Comment: You need to delete and recreate containers all the time; moving them between networks shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: @VishalVijayan I understand that you need to modify all the 45 containers if you need to create a user-defined network. by skipping that and trying to find a workaround you are not solving the problem instead you are extending it. As per my views it's worth if you update the existing containers. It will ease your future problems.